# Display Bootstrap Featurette with a foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach

Let’s say I have a foreach post that shows the last 5 posts, and I would like to position them as the boostrap featurette (with text and image changing To left and right side: example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/

i tried but it's not display well and not responsive. so if you have time, pls help.

```html
<div class="container">
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">{{ $post->title }}</h2>
        <p class="lead">{{ $post->title }}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="{{ asset('assets/img/laptop-1385702_1920.jpg') }}" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br> 
  @endforeach
</div>
```

--> not working  : [result](https://nimbusweb.me/nimbus-screenshots/cf8f328e3c8e255224dc4a6be922f565)

Comment: Hello, we need to see the code you try to help you.

Comment: ths for the quick reply, it's done.

Comment: Did you really use `bootstrap`, I do not find anything about `featurette` class in  `bootstrap` ?

Comment: i don't know but it's in bootstrap exemple, doesn't realy matter it's steel normal html and css responsive. this is my result when i customise the bootstrap featurette exemple :https://nimb.ws/rLxlMC

Comment: your `col` class is only working uptil `md` screen below that it wont be responsive anymore so you have to specify `col` for each screen like this `col-md-5 col-sm-12` and `align-self-center` will center your text with respect to the image vertically.

Comment: hm not working but i forget i can flex element with ```align-self-center``` thanks again i'm one the right road here.